# Hide element with a delay

Tags: javascript

In this case the element hides at ones. Can't understand why it's not show a "P" tag at first and then slowly hides it. Please, help me to fix a problem.

```js
var step = 0.1;
var delay = 90000;
var displayMe = function() {
  if (element.style.opacity < 1) {
    element.style.opacity += step;
    setTimeout('displayMe()', delay);
  }
}

var hideMe = function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('regform');
  if (elem.style.opacity >= 0) {
    elem.style.opacity -= step;
    setTimeout('hideMe ()', delay);
  }
}

hideMe();
```

```html
<p id="regform">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

`Element.style.prop` will read only inline styles. Define `style='opacity:1'` for `<p>` element.

```js
var step = 0.1;
var delay = 1000;

var displayMe = function() {
  if (element.style.opacity < 1) {
    element.style.opacity += step;
    setTimeout(displayMe, delay);
  }
}

var hideMe = function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('regform');
  if (elem.style.opacity >= 0) {
    elem.style.opacity -= step;
    setTimeout(hideMe, delay);
  }
}

hideMe();
```

```html
<p id="regform" style='opacity:1'>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 document.getElementById('regform').style.opacity=1;
 var hideMe = function()
 {
    var elem = document.getElementById('regform');
    if(elem.style.opacity>0)
    {
        elem.style.opacity-= step;
        setTimeout(hideMe, delay);
    }
 }
 hideMe();
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/shzL74Lt/)

Answer (score 0):

Try it with **jquery**:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#regform').delay(1000).fadeOut(2000);
      });
</script>

<p id="regform" style='opacity:1'>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
```

[Documentation **.fadeOut()**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

Comment: I need changes only in a code. Purpose is to use pure javascript.

Comment: Ok, I understand you. Remove my answer?